# PHP Page Failed to Load

Tags: php

I am having a problem with my files. I have to refresh the page several times to get it to load. Often the Chrome debug tools show the file in red. This happens for every page.

Is there a way to track what the problem is? My error_log for Apache doesn't say anything.
The odd thing is that the included JS/CSS files are inside that file that is failing.

[image]

Comment: Is your access logs consistent with your Chrome debug tool?

Comment: Check your code for a loop that is including the file/resource that is failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does apache's access.log say? Status 200?

In general, not the easiest way to resolve such issues, but quite reliable one is to listen to network traffic actually coming from the webserver. You can use [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) for that. Then take a look at the connection bringing the main HTML page (decode TCP stream) and think.

Overall, it looks like a webserver setup or internet connection issue to me.
Or could be a problem with your machine (running web browser): bad RAM or something.
Can you try it from another computer?
Chrome can make some bad jokes too: try restarting it just in case.